# How does AngularJs .Config works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I'm trying to create a navigation bar, this is how my html code looks like.....

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><span class="navbar-brand">Registration</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/Courses">Courses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Instructors">Instructors</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have put 'ng-app' tag in my Layout page............. My issue is when i click these two navigation buttons, it will give me an error page saying page not found(404 error code)......... this is how my module looks like.............

```
var registrationModule = angular.module("registrationModule", [])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when('/Courses', { templateUrl: '/Templates/Course.cshtml', controller: 'CoursesController' });

        $routeProvider.when('/Instructors', { templateUrl: '/Templates/Instructor.cshtml', controller: 'InstructorsController' });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    })
;
```

These are the two templates i have created..........
1. Course.cshtml:

```
<div class="row">
    <h2>Course</h2>
    <div class="span10">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Course</th>
                <th>Course Name</th>
                <th>Instructor</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="course in courses">
                <td>{{course.number}}</td>
                <td>{{course.name}}</td>
                <td>{{course.instructor}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

2.Instructor.cshtml:

```
<div class="row">
    <h2>Instructor</h2>
    <div class="span10">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Room Number</th>
                <th>Instructor's Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="instructor in instructors">
                <td>{{instructor.roomNumber}}</td>
                <td>{{instructor.name}}</td>
                <td>{{instructor.email}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you set up server to recognize the html5 mode virtual directories?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access cshtml file through url because they are nothing but analysed `C#` razor engine, I'd prefer you to load those .cshtml file from controller action. Instead of directive path of `cshtml` load it using asp.net mvc controller action.

**CODE**

```
var registrationModule = angular.module("registrationModule", [])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/Courses', {
    //templates controller Course action will return Course.cshtml
    templateUrl: '/Templates/Course',
    controller: 'CoursesController'
  });

  $routeProvider.when('/Instructors', {
    //templates controller Instructor action will return Instructor.cshtml
    templateUrl: '/Templates/Instructor',
    controller: 'InstructorsController'
  });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
```

Comment: You have invalid syntax. Why would your code do anything different than OP code (assuming syntax is fixed)?

Comment: @charlietfl yes that was my bad, its related to `C#` side